# Windows 10 virtual keyboard disappears from login screen when password box is visible

Tags: windows-10, accessibility, virtual-keyboard

I have a Windows 10 laptop with several bad keys, and have to use the On-Screen Keyboard to log in and do other stuff. I keep the virtual keyboard app running at all times. However, the virtual keyboard now disappears from the login screen when I type my password. The only way to prevent this is to close the virtual keyboard after waking up the computer from sleep, and then relaunch it from the accessibility options on the login screen.

This only started happening a few days ago, and restarting my computer did not make a difference. I had not changed any settings. Anyone have an idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Perhaps the keyboard is generating phantom key-presses? You should really have it fixed.

Comment: I don't believe that is the case. If it was, I would likely have noticed it already. I also don't think phantom key presses would cause the On-Screen Keyboard to disappear.

Comment: They would. But could be a lots of things, including just a buggy behaviour, which I'm actually kind of experiencing myself in a similar manner - sometimes my log in screen gets closed to initial status (no password input) when typing password with regular keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem, KB5025221 has to be the reason.

I am using two computers, I removed KB5025221 from one of them and problem disappeared.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one! I guess this answers my question.